# Reference to a bxslider after it has been created

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Is it possible to get a reference to a [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/) that has been applied to an element, after it has been created?

Commonly, you can get a reference when a slider if first created.

```
var mySlider;
$(function(){
    mySlider = $('#slider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        controls: true
    });
});
```

However, if you have multiple sliders on the same page, and all are being reference by a class instead of an id, it would be nice to be able to get a reference to the slider object, after the fact.

For example

HTML:

```
<ul class="slider" id="my-specific-slider">...</ul>
<ul class="slider" >...</ul>
<ul class="slider" >...</ul>
```

JS:

```
var mySlider;
$(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        controls: true
    });

    myslider = $('#my-specific-slider').XXX;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need the answer but I would suggest to use a each().

```
$(function(){
    $(".slider").each(function() {
        eleId = $(this).attr('id');
        if (eleId) {
            eleId = $(this).bxSlider({
                auto: true,
                controls: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not quite what I've after, but if that was changed slightly to record the result of the bxSlider constructor against a data() item of the element, then that would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
var bxObject = $(".bxslider").data("bxSlider");
bxObject.goToSlide(3);
```